# Symbol file not loading for debugging custom project in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have a large solution in Visual Studio 2012 which consists of executables and class library projects.
When debugging the application the breakpoints in one particular class library project are not being hit.

I looked at the **Debug> Windows> Modules** window to check the status of the symbols for that project and it says **"Cannot find or open the PDB file"**.
It also says **"No"** under the **"User Code"** column.
I notice that there are a few other of the custom projects in the solution that are showing "No" in that column and their symbols are also failing to load. Anything with a "Yes" under "User code" seems to have had it's pdb loaded no problem. But I'm not sure if this is relevant.

I have used **dumpbin /headers** on the dll and the path for the pdb file is present and correct.

The module is definitely not in the exclude list for the symbol loading.

I have also tried right clicking on the entry in the modules window, selecting **"Load symbols"** and navigating to the path given in the dll header. When I select the pdb it says **"A matching symbol file was not found in this folder"**.

I get this after I have deleted these folders and files, cleaned the solution, closed it and rebuilt the whole thing.
The pdb was definitely built at the same time as the dll in question.

So clearly the problem is the "cannot open the pdb" portion of the error message.

I have tried this on 2 computers and both are exhibiting the same behaviour.

Can anyone offer any suggestions on where to go from here, and perhaps why on earth the built pdb corresponding to the dll won't load for it?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I tried a few tools to check if the pdb and the dll actually matched, and using [chkmatch](http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/chkmatch.html) I could see that the GUIDs in the dll being run and the pdb in the obj folder didn't match.

So it turns out that although the dll and pdb in the project's obj folder are a match, the dll that was actually getting copied to the application's destination folder by a post-build event was the old dll from the previous build.

The post-build event was running before that particular project had built, or at least finished building, and was copying in the existing dll from the bin which was subsequently overwritten by the continuing build.

I have resolved the problem by editing the project dependencies for the solution and ensuring that the project with the post-build event is dependent on the project that wasn't loading, and now the pdb loads during debug.

Comment: I have the same problem and by reading your solution I still don't understand what you did to solve it. Could you explain more detailed?

Comment: Basically my projects were building in the wrong order. When you right click on your Solution in Visual Studio 2012 there's a Project Dependencies option and on the window that opens there's a Build order tab where you can set the order the projects are built in.

Comment: I tried adding a pdb file from another folder, downloadng symbols(it started downloading MS symbols, so stopped it), specifying modules to load - None worked. My problem was that I was getting the dll from Nuget and the pdb from the source I had. I copied the dll from the source I had and it worked!

Answer (score 37):

I simply deleted bin and obj folder from the startup project folder and rebuild the solution.

Comment: Works for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

For me I just deleted the project from IIS and created it again and it works fine

Comment: Cleaning the solution did not work for me but resetting local IIS did the trick. Apparently some assemblies were still cached.

Answer (score 9):

For me it helped to use chkmatch tool and then just close and open visual studio, make clean and rebuild. Now my pdb gets also loaded. You can make sure it does, as Nanhydrin pointed out, from Debug -> Windows -> Modules - this view is only accessible during debugging.

Answer (score 9):

I found that the project I was receiving the message about, was being optimized when built.

I went into the projects properties, Compile Tab, Advanced Compile Options... and unchecked the `Enable Optimizations` checkbox

[image: Deselect Enable Optimizations]

Comment: I just unticked 'Optimize code' in the csproj properties.

Answer (score 9):

In my case there was a check mark on `Enable Just My Code` in `Tools>>Options>>Debugging>>General`.

I unchecked it and it worked.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4brp.jpg)

[image]

Comment: In my case the opposite worked - I had 'Symbol file not loaded' error and checking 'Enable Just My Code' resolved the issue.

Answer (score 7):

In my case older version of referenced dll was in my GAC. Cleared it out, and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

Reminder: Put the project into "Debug" configuration... for those like me who forget and feel silly.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this issue and thought I would put my fix here, as it my help others (maybe even myself again?!) in the future...

Make sure that when you are attaching to the process on the remote server, that the "Attach to" is set to

> Automatically determine the type of code to debug

To do this, When the server qualifier has been provided and a list of processes is visible, click the "Select" button next to the "Attach to" input.

[image: Image 1]
Then, select "Automatically determine the type of code to debug" and OK out of the screen, then attach.

[image: Image 2]

This fixed the issue for me, at least.

Answer (score 2):

Deleted the project from solution and added it again to the solution worked for me. :)

Answer (score 2):

Bit late to the party here - just in case this is helpful.

We have a couple of separate websites (in different solutions in Visual Studio). On initial load of one of the sites, we were making a call to the other site which would return an image.

Both of these sites referenced a common DLL, but while working on one site, had not realised that the other site had been left in a 'Release' build - after the site loaded, the offending DLL was rebuilt, but without symbols.

Kudos to Nanhydrin for both mentioning the modules debug window (very helpful) and for putting me on the right track with the post build event.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from another thread that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28476665/5969306
- In Visual Studio: Project Properties -> Build -> Advanced button -> Debug info drop-down and make sure the value is not “none”.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check options from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38377530/6911991
2. Click **Advanced** and check that **Debugging Information** is set to FULL
   [image: Advanced tab screenshot]
3. Check **Run Configuration** in all projects in the solution

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue , tried all the other solutions (it took 2 days !! I'm crying... !TWO DAYS!) But finally I realized that my file was registered in GAC, I removed it and the problem was resolved.

At the command prompt, type the following command:

```
gacutil –u <assembly name>
```

[How to: Remove an Assembly from the Global Assembly Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-remove-an-assembly-from-the-gac)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by disabling 'Use Managed Compatibility Mode' in the *Debug->Options* menu:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a line like this in my debug window:

> Symbols for the module 'MyModule.dll' were not loaded.

I removed the 'Optimize code' option in Project properties -> Build. And the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be due to **wrong reference of dlls** used in project.

Delete **obj** and **bin** folders in current project and **build** project again.

Answer (score 0):

Check for permission to ASP.NET Temporary folder:

```
"c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files"
```

User of application pool has to have the rights to subfolder with ASP.NET files, something like:

```
root\60039743\c28e12ee
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the dependency of your dll, if you added to the solution, this can cause failure in loading symbols.