# C# Remote Debugger - Cannot find or open the PDB file

Tags: c#, remote-debugging

I'm trying to remote debug my application (C# windows application) according to [Remote Debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx), I installed the Remote Tools on my remote machine, say it's **RA**, and I added permission for the machine I want to debug the application, say it's **B**.

I open VS in **B**, Click Debug->Attach to Process..., choose 'Remote =(no authenticated) in Transport, then click the Find button and I can find the machine **RA**. When I selected this machine and choose the application I'm going to debug, but when I attach it, there's a lot log messages showing that `Cannot find or open the PDB file`.

Since we need the `pdb` files to debug on our local machine, then how remote debugging find the `pdb` files? Or I didn't have it configured correctly on **RA**?

Comment: Why not copy the .pdb files along with the application to the remote location?

Comment: I do have the pdb files in the remote machine, I usually debug locally in the remote machine. Now I'm trying to debug in another machine, the remote machine is a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Confirm yourself that you can access the pdb files, located on RA, from B. First step is to make a network share of the directory where the pdb's are located on RA. Second step is to open a windows explorer on B and navigate to that specific network share. For example: \\RA-MACHINE\PDB-DIR. Log in with the correct credentials (RA-DOMAIN\RA-USER, RA-PWD) and tell it to remember your credentials for subsequent logins. The pdb-files should show up in the windows explorer. Configure where the debugger looks for symbol files, as described [[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger)] and remote debugging should work.

Comment: After having carried out a broad number of other suggested [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109575/symbol-file-not-loading-for-debugging-custom-project-in-visual-studio-2012/18126332)... of which none worked, I finally found this one that did the trick. However, I circumvented the direct n/w share & used the Admin drive share + full path to the pdb file location. Nevertheless, the question remains at large why the standard configuration fails that does not require pointing to the symbol file.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/x54fht41(v=vs.100).aspx

> By default, the debugger loads symbol files from the location where
>   your EXE is located. To use symbols from another directory or a symbol
>   server, you must specify the locations to Visual Studio.

Comment: I added a remote folder as the symbol file location.  But the breakpoint is still disabled. And the log message is changed, it says that `Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Azure pipelines with VS 2022 and your .pdb file is present in your web app, you have to publish manually in VS with a profile and then attach the debugger. I tried to get my pipeline to update the .pdb file but was unsuccessful. I never had this issue with VS 2019.