# VS 2019 remote debugging can't "see" my symbols (C++)

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2019, remote-debugging

Sorry if this is a duplicate -- I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739764/c-sharp-remote-debugger-cannot-find-or-open-the-pdb-file) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109575/symbol-file-not-loading-for-debugging-custom-project-in-visual-studio-2012/18126332) and others, but I can't find my problem.

A program I build debugs successfully on my local machine, but when I try to debug it remotely, I can't set breakpoints in my code. I've opened the modules window in the debugger, and under Symbol Status for my executable, it tells me "Cannot find or open the PDB file." I try to load it manually, and get the error, "A matching symbol file was not found in this folder."

I created a minimal (hello world) app, and I can debug that, so I'm able to reach the remote PC. Indeed, the app does start up and run on the remote system. So, it isn't an access issue.

Not sure what else to say about this, other than to show you my project debugging configuration:
[image]

Any ideas are MOST welcome. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer -- I needed to check the "deploy" box in the Configuration Manager window. This surprised me a little, as using the "deploy" command (available from right-clicking the project property) didn't do the trick. Evidently, there's some behind-the-scenes magic that takes place when the deploy box is checked.