# Use Azure DevOps Symbols for Visual Studio Debug Symbol Source

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

I try to use Azure DevOps Server (on prem) the output of the `Index sources and publish symbols` task as Symbol Input for the Visual Studio Debugger. Therefore I copy the task output to a local directory on my machine and configure the `Symbol file (.pdb) locations` on VS to that path.

The Symbols comes from a *NuGet Package* (name: `ExceptionPackage`) I created specially for that use case. The packages only purpose is to throw an exception on calling different function to test the Symbol Debugging with VS.

The VS Debug Settings for the Symbol file locations looks like:

[image]

When I run my test code, the Debugger is not able to give me a *full* `Call Stack` of the NuGet Package, even when I add all levels of my Symbol path (`C:\Users\m**\Desktop\DebugTest\Symbols` is the root folder with multiple symbol sources). *Is the root path enough for VS?*

[image]

**So how do I get the full the `Call Stack` of the Exception inside my NuGet Package? Is my approach wrong?**

---

### VS General Debugger Settings:

[image]

---

### Versions:

- **Azure DevOps Server:**  17.153.29207.5 (AzureDevOps2019.Update1)
- **Visual Studio 2019:** 16.7.7

Answer (score 0):

> Use Azure DevOps Symbols for Visual Studio Debug Symbol Source

I could also reproduce this issue on my side. I check the Symbols load information from the Modules Window:

[image]

I get the error `PDB does not match image.`. Even if I match the pdb file manually, it still not work:

[image]

Then I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109575/symbol-file-not-loading-for-debugging-custom-project-in-visual-studio-2012) about this issue.

To debug the nuget package, you could try to use the lightweight solution to debug the nuget package:

[Is it possible to host both regular and symbols packages in a NuGet local feed on a network share?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45620764/is-it-possible-to-host-both-regular-and-symbols-packages-in-a-nuget-local-feed-o)

And if possible, please check if [this thread](https://capgemini.github.io/development/debugging-into-a-nuget-package/) give any helps.