# Visual Studio Profiler error "symbol file does not contain source information or cannot be found"

Tags: visual-studio, profiler

I get below error when I try to open the source code of DLL used in profiler report.

- Profiling Type: Instrumentation
- application  Configuration: Debug ,any-cpu
- DLL Configuration :Debug ,any-cpu
- Visual studio : 2017,2019,2022

I was able to open source code in CPU profiling report but not opening in Instrumentation Profiling report.

CPU Profiler:

[image]

Instrumentation Profiler:

[image: Instrumentation Profiler]

Clicked on Symbol settings and added .pdb file path. But the source code not loading.  How to view source code of DLL in Instrumentation Profiler report.

Comment: I think this might helps you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109575/symbol-file-not-loading-for-debugging-custom-project-in-visual-studio-2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Performance Explorer window,

1. Under profiler session - Right-click Targets and then select Add Target
   Binary-> select the .dll  file
2. Right click on session and select start profiling

In the New Instrumentation report I am able open source code of DLL.